# awk all lines of the input file where first and the second field are the same

Tags: awk, field, matching

I am having time here with the following task. I need to print all lines of the input file
where 1st field matches the 2nd. Here is my syntax, which apparently is not working:
awk '$1==$2 {print $0}' < inputfile, any ideas what is wrong ?

Comment: ED,
Misspelled the question.

Comment: I'm betting your field separator is not a space but post some small sample input and expected output so we can see.

Answer (score 2):

The third field would be `$3`, no?

```
awk '$1==$3' inputfile
```

(Since we're here, you could delete the `print $0`, which is implied, and also the `<` redirection.)